# How to separate string after whitespace in c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm using c# and  have a string like x="12 $Math A Level$"` that could be also x="12 Math A Level"

How can I separate this string in order to have a variable `year=12` and `subject=Math A Level`?

I was using something like:

```
char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
var x = item.Split(whitespace);
```

but then I didn't know what to do after or if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: If your delimiter is `$`, why do you split on space and tab?

Comment: Do you have more examples? Are they all built like this? `"<some num> $<some text>$"` ?

Comment: @Heinzi How could I split it using $? And if, for example, I had the string like x="12 Math A Level" how could i split this?

Comment: @Fildor some of them are like that and others are like "<some num> <some text>" whithout the $

Comment: If you want to extract part of the string before the *first* space, then you might want to use `IndexOf` to find the first space and `Substring` to split the text at that space.

Comment: _"some of them are like that and others are like "..." whithout the $"_  - That's an important information you should add to the question. Otherwise you could have tried with regex (which I really do not recommend often): https://regex101.com/r/NtQT8a/1

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh okay! If I had the string like x="12 Math A Level". How would I divide it them?

Comment: @JonasH yes sorry, I'm new to this. I updated the question

Comment: Is it always going to be `<number><space><text>`? Because that makes it pretty easy to use `string.Split(' ', 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = "12 $Math A Level$".Split('$', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);

string year = x[0];
string subject = x[1];

Console.WriteLine(year);
Console.WriteLine(subject);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the override of split that takes the count :

```
var examples = new []{"2 $Math A Level$", "<some_num> <some text>"} ;

foreach(var s in examples)
{


var parts = s.Split(' ', count: 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);

Console.WriteLine($"'{parts[0]}', '{parts[1]}'");
}
```

This prints:

```
'2', '$Math A Level$'
'<some_num>', '<some text>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var item = "12 Math A Level";
var index = item.IndexOf(' ');
var year = item.Substring(0, index);
var subject = item.Substring(index + 1, item.Length - index-1).Trim('$');
```

This assumes that the year is the first word, and the subject is everything else. It also assumes you are not interested in any '$' signs. You might also want to add a check that the index was actually found, in case there are no spaces in the string.

Answer (score 1):

To add a Regex-based answer:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    
    public static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<ID>[0-9]+)\s+[$]?(?<Text>[^$]*)[$]?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static void Main()
    {
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("12 $Math A Level$");
        
        foreach( Match m in matches )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(m.Groups["ID"].Value)} | {(m.Groups["Text"].Value)}");
        }
        
        matches = regex.Matches("13 Math B Level");
        
        foreach( Match m in matches )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(m.Groups["ID"].Value)} | {(m.Groups["Text"].Value)}");
        }
    }
}
```

In action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6XEQw8

Output:

```
12 | Math A Level
13 | Math B Level
```

To explain the expression:

```
(?[0-9]+)\s+[$]?(?[^$]*)[$]?
(?[0-9]+)  - Named Catpure-Group "ID"
      [0-9]    - Match literal chars '0' to '9'
           +   - ^^ One or more times
\s+            - Match whitespace one or more times
[$]?           - Match literal '$' one or zero times
(?[^$]*) - Named Capture-Group "Text"
        [^$]   - Match anything that is _not_ literal '$'
            *  - ^^ Zero or more times
[$]?           - Match literal '$' one or zero times
```

See also https://regex101.com/r/WV366l/1

---

**Mind:** I personally would [benchmark](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) this solution against a (or several) non-regex solutions and then make a choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the string format specified (`"12 $Math A Level$"`), you could split with at `$` like this:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sample = "12 $Math A Level$";
        var rec = Parse(sample);
                
        Console.WriteLine($"Year={rec.Year}\nSubject={rec.Subject}");
    }
    
    private static Record Parse(string value)
    {
        var delimiter = new char[] { '$' };
        var parts = value.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new Record { Year = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]), Subject = parts[1] };
    }
    
    public class Record
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

###### Output:

> ```
> Year=12
> Subject=Math A Level
> ```

### ▶️ Try it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DAFLjA

Comment: "some of them are like that and others are like "<some num> <some text>" whithout the $ –  nina"

Comment: Well, this post-filed information obviously changes everything.
It then all hangs on the possible format variants that were not clear at the beginning.